# Compiler fails to deduce types when using std::function

Tags: c++, overloading, type-deduction

So, I have a method and its overload for a class, written like this:

```
bool my_for_each(someIterator begin, someIterator end, bool (*_lambda)(someIterator));

void my_for_each(someIterator begin, someIterator end, void (*_lambda)(someIterator));
```

As you can see, the only difference is the signature of a passed function, that is, its return type.
Although the code above works perfectly fine when i call it:

```
my_for_each(iteratorBegin, iteratorEnd, [](someIterator) {; }); // calls void version

my_for_each(iteratorBegin, iteratorEnd, [](someIterator)->bool {return false; }); // calls bool version
```

..., if I write the my_for_each function as follows:

```
bool my_for_each(someIterator begin, someIterator end, std::function<bool(someIterator)> _lambda);

void my_for_each(someIterator begin, someIterator end, std::function<void(someIterator)> _lambda);
```

The code fails to compile if i call the function the same way (C2668 ambiguous call to overloaded function). Although, if I manually cast the function:

```
my_for_each(iteratorBegin, iteratorEnd, static_cast<std::function<void(someIterator)>>([](someIterator) {; })); //calls void version

my_for_each(iteratorBegin, iteratorEnd, static_cast<std::function<bool(someIterator)>>([](someIterator) -> bool { return false; })); //calls bool version
```

The code works perfectly fine. So I'm just wondering:

1. Why is normal function pointer type deduction "stronger" than the std template one?
2. Is there some kinda workaround to still use the more generic version, while not casting the parameter manually?

The compiler is VS2015.

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux fixed, just a transcription error

Comment: What is the meaning of the return values for the `my_for_each` functions?

Comment: It appears to be two iterators forming a range, and a function which accepts an iterator and does something to it. I’m not sure what is being done with all the `bool`s in the second version (presumably either an and or an or operation).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It returns true if every lambda call returned true, false otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::function` and lambdas have distinct types, meaning the 2nd example requires an implicit conversion from the lambda's type to `std::function`.

The problem is that the lambda that returns `bool` can be implicitly converted to both `std::function<bool(T)>` and `std::function<void(T)>`, thus both overloads are equally valid choices for your call, leading to an ambiguity error. When you manually cast them to the proper `std::function` the ambiguity is explicitly resolved.

Edit : Workaround

You can solve this problem by providing an addition templated overload that accepts any kind of callable type, deduces the return type for that callable type and preforms the cast automatically. I've changed `someIterator` to a template argument for generality. Since you haven't provided implementation details for your `my_for_each` functions, I have omitted those implementations. Since it appears that you only want to support `void` and `bool` return types, I've added a `static_assert` to generate a clear compiler error in case unsupported return types are provided.

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

// Implement for std::function<bool(iter)>
template<class I>
bool my_for_each(I begin, I end, std::function<bool(I)> lambda);

// Implement for std::function<void(iter)>
template<class I>
void my_for_each(I begin, I end, std::function<void(I)> lambda);

// Dispatch to the right overload
template<class T, class I>
auto my_for_each(I begin, I end, T&& lambda)
{
    using return_type = decltype(lambda(begin));    // Obtain the return type of lambda
    static_assert(std::is_same<return_type, bool>::value || std::is_same<return_type, void>::value,
        "my_for_each only accepts function objects that return void or bool");
    using function_type = std::function<return_type(I)>;    // The type to cast lambda to
    return my_for_each(begin, end, function_type(std::forward<T>(lambda))); // Preform the cast
}
```

Comment: A fix would improve this answer.

Comment: So, if i want to use my own callable objects, I have to static_cast them every time, is that correct?

Comment: @Alfaix I've edited the answer with a fix to avoid having to manually cast every time.

Comment: @Yakk Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the fact that non-capturing lambdas are only convertible to function pointer which would accept arguments of used types.

On the other hand, `std::function` has a templated constructor which accepts everything. So both `std::function<bool...>` and  `std::function<void ...>` could be created from your lambda for overload resolution of `my_for_each`. (Note, that it would not be possible to create those objects, though).